# I can bind to port 80 as a non-root user in a docker container. Why? What's going on?

Tags: docker

Short version:

I can bind to port 80 inside a docker container while running as a non-root user. Please explain.

Long version:

I'm newish to docker, but have a lot of experience otherwise. Everything is making sense to me except this behavior.

I've tried with both the Google centos base image, and the latest docker ubuntu image.

I build a docker image off those bases with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM marketplace.gcr.io/google/centos7

# or for ubuntu
# FROM ubuntu
# RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python

RUN groupadd -g 1000 container && useradd -r -u 1000 -g container container
USER container
```

Great. Then I build and run it with `docker run --rm -it <img_name>`, and now I'm in the container with `whoami` returning "container". I don't have root privileges. `touch /root/foo` fails with access denied.

Ok, cool. Non-root user, running without root privileges. I can't `sudo`. I can't `su root`. Just like I expect.

Then I run:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80` and it happily binds to port 80. I can run `curl localhost` inside the container and I get a response.

What's going on? What am I missing.

Thanks for any help.

I'm running Docker for Mac if it matters. I don't expect it does. (I expected wrong.)

Comment: can you show your run command? Do you port forward, 8080:80, for example?

Comment: Added run command. Nope, not mapping ports. It's about what happens in the container itself.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to be root to bind to lower ports but the process has to have the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` [capability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). You can check the capabilities of your shell with `getpcaps $$` (part of the `libcap2-bin` package in ubuntu). But these are usually dropped as a non-root user, also in a `docker` container...

Answer (score 5):

This behavior was [added in 20.3.0](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41030) by changing the value of `net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start` inside the network namespace to be `0`, effectively making all ports unprivileged. Since containers typically run a single app, there's little value to restricting that app to only listen on privileged ports like you would want on a multi-user host.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this with ubuntu:18.04 image on Linux Host and it fails to bind to port 80.
I repeated on a Mac and the same that is happening to you happened there.

Now on the Mac you CAN bind to lower ports with non root user (just try running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80` as your login user) So maybe this is normal on the Mac.

Comment: Thanks for testing it! Super weird. I would think that the linux vm that is running docker on the Mac would complain. I guess it gets passed through somehow? I never realized I could bind low ports as a regular user on my mac. Thanks again.

Comment: do you have AuthBind on your mac?

Comment: Nah, as of Mojave they allow any user to bind any port. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18302380

Comment: This does not really explain this behavior since the `python` command in run inside the `docker` container i.e. inside the Linux VM, so binding to port 80 requires the correct permission under Linux. Maybe there is a special configuration of the effective capabilities of containers in the Docker for Mac setup?